# how to connect to google account automatically

Tags: angular, google-api, google-authentication

I'm programing a website with angular and will show the statistics from google analytics and the calendar from google calendar in the dashboard.
I want to link my website to my Google account with reason to don't connect every time to my Google account so is there any solution to do the auth2 in the backend without insert every time the email and the password

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after loading the auth2 I tried to Sing-in by writing the sign-in function after it and in options, I specified the login hit by writing the email I want to connect to it

```
export class GoogleService {

  
private user = new ReplaySubject<gapi.auth2.GoogleUser>(1);
  

constructor(
  private analytics : AnalyticsService, 
  private calendar : CalendarService
 ) { 
 gapi.load('auth2',()=>{
  gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id : '<client-Id>'
  }).then(res=>{

    if(res.isSignedIn.get()){
      //if the user already sign in 
      this.user.next(res.currentUser.get());
      this.analytics.getReportes();
      this.calendar.getEventsApi();
      
    }else{
      
      res.signIn({
        scope : 
          // See, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar '+
    
          // View and edit events on all your calendars
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events '+
    
          // View events on all your calendars
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly '+
    
          // See and download any calendar you can access using your Google Calendar
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly '+
    
          // View your Calendar settings
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly '+

          // View analytics reports 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' ,

        //account to connect
          login_hint:'<account-email>'
  
      }).then(user=>{
        this.user.next(user);
        this.analytics.getReportes();
        this.calendar.getEventsApi();
      }).catch(()=>{
        this.user.next(null)
      })
    }

  })
 })
}



public observable() : Observable<gapi.auth2.GoogleUser>{
  return this.user.asObservable();
}

  
}
```

the first time it will demand the password and after sign-in and register the password the next time will connect automatically.

this worked for me!